# C# How to bind WPF scrollbar value to ViewModel with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I am trying to bind a scrollbar value from my XAML to a property in my ViewModel in C#. I am able to bind other control values, like buttons and textblocks, but I can't seem to figure out the solution for a scroll bar. I am using Caliburn.Micro to establish my MVVM.

Below, I have a textblock and a scrollbar. The textblock works fine, but the scrollbar does not seem to link to the ScrollValue property. A section of the XAML looks like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ApproachHeight"/>
<ScrollBar x:Name="ScrollValue"/>
```

A section of the C# ViewModel looks like:

```
private double _approachHeight = 250;
private double _scrollValue;

public double ApproachHeight
{
    get
    {
        return _approachHeight;
    }
    set
    {
        _approachHeight = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ApproachHeight);
    }
}

public double ScrollValue
{
    get
    {
        return _scrollValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _scrollValue = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ScrollValue);
    }
}
```

I figured the scrollbar would just bind its value the same way a textblock does, but that doesn't seem to be working.

I am a beginner to WPF and MVVM so I apologize if my terminology is wrong. Any ideas on how to link a Scrollbar value to a property of my ViewModel would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the `Value` attribute of `ScrollBar` using standard WPF binding:

```
<ScrollBar Value="{Binding ScrollValue}"/>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for answering my question.